# Is there anything specific required for a dog first aid kit?

Tags: hiking, first-aid, dogs

You can go into almost any pet store in the UK, especially the big chains, and see first aid kits for your dog.

Is there anything specifically required for a dog first aid kit, or will a human first aid kit cover what is needed for a dog as well?

Comment: TBH, I don't really rate human first aid kits (off the shelf one's anyway). It's much **better** and **cheaper** to build your own.

Comment: @Liam oh I know that, that's not the question. We have our first aid kit, but if the dog recommended ones are basically the same as a humans, why make up two? That's the info I'm after.

Comment: Is this for a home kit, or to carry if you're hillwalking with a dog (for instance?)

Comment: @Roddy for hiking. Sorry I did include the tag but didn't specify :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are often basically the same but there are often three additional items listed:

- tick tweezers
- louse-comb
- foldable cone (to be preferred), muzzle or strips of cloth to prevent biting (its wounds etc.)

Especially the tick tweezers seems to be pretty useful of course.

---

Other [pet-specific supplies](http://www.humanesociety.org/animals/resources/tips/pet_first_aid_kit.html) to assume

> - Pet first-aid book
> - Phone numbers: your veterinarian, the nearest emergency-veterinary clinic (along with directions!) and a poison-control center or hotline
> - Paperwork for your pet (in a waterproof container or bag): proof of rabies-vaccination status, copies of other important medical records
>     and a current photo of your pet (in case he gets lost)
> - Nylon leash
> - Self-cling bandage (bandage that stretches and sticks to itself but not to fur—available at pet stores and from pet-supply catalogs)
> - Muzzle or strips of cloth to prevent biting (don't use this if your pet is vomiting, choking, coughing or otherwise having difficulty
>     breathing)

Comment: I assume the muzzle is to prevent the dog from biting a wound more than anything else?

Comment: @Aravona Of course :)

Comment: A "cone" would do a similar task

Comment: @Liam Not very practical to carry one around in a first-aid kid imho

Comment: You can get soft one's the fold up quite small. Depends on the size of your dog (bigger dog -> bigger cone) too. Our's probably packs down to 3"long. Easy to slide down the side of a pack

Comment: @Liam a foldable cone is more preferable in my mind... They can still eat and drink easily then too. Great point.

Comment: @Liam Didn't know that. Added the cone

Comment: I always carry tick remover in my own kit. However, I hadn't appreciated that dogs can get Lymes disease as well as humans....

Comment: Wouldn't bother with a cone in a portable kit. Cone is typically to stop a dog taking out stitches, and you're not going to be sewing up your pooch on the hill.

Comment: The  muzzle is also useful to prevent your dog from biting someone else that  may be assisting - while you may trust your dog not to bite you  even if he's injured (that's probably misplaced trust if the dog is in serious pain),  when your dog suffers a painful broken leg, do you do you trust him to not bite the stranger that volunteered to help you to carry him off the trail?

Comment: @Johnny that is a fair point, though I've seen people get a German Shepard into a rucksack before because it was injured and carry it down.

Answer (score 8):

I just looked at a typical UK "Pet First Aid Kit" here.

http://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/dog/dog-healthcare/dog-first-aid/first-aid-box-for-pets

Contents are...

> Each pack contains 24 pieces all designed with the care of your pet in
>   mind, including:
>
> - 2 x 20ml Pods of Saline - to wash away dirt and debris from your    pet's eyes and other areas;
> - 2 x Medium Dressing Bandages with Ties -    to cover an injury;
> - 1 x Foil Blanket - to retain body warmth and help    combat shock;
> - 5 x Gauze Swabs - for cleaning up fluid or after saline    use;
> - 1 x Microporous Tape - to help hold dressings in place;
> - 1 x Conforming Bandage - for use with suspected sprained joints;
> - 2 x Pairs of Latex Gloves;
> - **4 x Plastic Pouches - to cover foot injuries    and help keep them clean;**
> - 4 x Alcohol Free Cleansing Wipes - to clean    wounds;
> - 1 x Scissors;
> - 1 x Tweezers.

All in all, remarkably similar to a standard human kit. The pouches for foot injuries are the only interesting addition - Your dog doesn't wear boots, so a foot injury is going to get filthy without something like this - although you could reasonably improvise something.

I'd just double check my 'human' kit, and make sure I have enough to cope with both a dog and a human injury.

Side note: *LATEX* gloves? No, get nitrile ones instead. I don't think dogs can be allergic to latex, but who knows who you're going to treat...?

Comment: This is really good info, and yeah my friend has dog boots in her first aid kit! And that was in fact the exact store that sprung the question as we go there weekly :)

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the size of your dog you should also consider getting some larger bandages - A Labrador is very large around compared to a human leg. 
Also I would suggest some plastic bags - They can be used in conjunction with the self cling bandages over a leg, foot or tail wound. Also, as in a human, for penetrating or sucking wounds.

Something for stings as well such as piriton liquid (Dogs are great at biting wasps) and the liquid is easier to get down them if the sting is in the mouth or throat. Make sure you know the dose for your particular dog though (your vet should be able to advise) - This is only for an emergency where you cannot get to a vet in time.

For ticks and other such nasties I keep tea-tree oil which I put on before removal as well as after - ticks are not keen on it and some will withdraw into themselves which helps with removal.

If you have scissors in your pack - make sure they are of the rounded end type = not just the tops rounded but both parts. A dog will not always hold still and it is so easy to jab by accident.

I really hope you never have to try any of these items out!

Comment: We'd always have poo bags which would work for our size dog but actually the plastic bag idea is really good.